# tax identification number in W8-BEN - Canada specific question

Tags: united-states, income, self-employment, contractor, form-w-8-ben

I live in Canada and have done a contract job with a U.S. company, and they ask me to fill a W8-BEN form to pay me.

I'm asked to `note that on the W8-BEN Form either section 5 or section 6 must be completed.`

Here's the section 5 and 6:
[image]

I've read the instructions on [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/iw8ben), which says:

If you do not have an SSN and are not eligible to get one, you can get an individual taxpayer identification number (ITIN). To apply for an ITIN, file Form W-7 with the IRS. It usually takes 4-6 weeks to get an ITIN. To claim certain treaty benefits, you must complete line 5 by submitting an SSN or ITIN, or line 6 by providing a foreign tax identification number (foreign TIN).

A search shows [this website](https://www.freshbooks.com/blog/w-8ben-form-canada-tax) suggests using the SIN (social insurance number) from the Canadian government.

My questions is that, is it a *safe* practice to use my SIN as the foreign TIN to fill in the W8-BEN form?

Comment: [another source](https://www.thebalance.com/us-withholding-for-canadian-independent-contractors-3193495): `On-Line 6 write in your US tax identification number (such as a Social Security Number, individual taxpayer identification number, or employer identification number)`

Comment: i called CRA and their answer is basically, `as long as you pay income tax in Canada, we do not care about the tax in the states.`. They mention that it is not uncommon for a US company to ask for SIN. I also ask if they recommend me calling the IRS, and they say `it is good to double check`